# why are the conditions in my if statement being ignored? C#

Tags: if-statement, unity-game-engine

I know this is a beginner's problem but I cannot progress with my studies until I understand what is going on here. In an if block that I'm executing in Update(), I cannot understand why the two if statements are executed simultaneously. I thought that as soon as the initiative variable was initialized at the start of the block, the compiler would move down to the first if statement to see if the condition is true. If it is true, it would execute the code in that block until the timer reached zero. Then it would move down to the next. If the condition was true in the first, then it would be false in the second so it would move up to the beginning again. A new bool value would be calculated for initiative and the process would be repeated. What's blowing my mind is that no matter what I do, both blocks are executed and the timers are completely ignored. It is very confusing!

I've made some very basic code to highlight the problem I'm having. I'm using this C# code in Unity3d:

```
public float firstTimer = 2;
public float secondTimer = 10; 
public bool initiative; 

void Update()
{

    initiative = InitiativeOrder(); 

    if(initiative == true && firstTimer > 0);
    {
        firstTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log ("First timer has finished!"); 
    }

    if(initiative == false && secondTimer > 0);
    {
        secondTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log ("Second timer has finished!"); 
    }
}

public bool InitiativeOrder()
{
    float player =  Random.Range(1,10); 
    float enemy = Random.Range(1,10); 

    if(player > enemy)
    {
        return true; 
    }
    else if (player < enemy)
    {
        return false; 
    }
    else 
    {
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the ; from after your if() if(initiative == true && firstTimer > 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason the timer isnt working is because the ; after your if()

```
if(initiative == true && firstTimer > 0);<----remove these from your if
```

make your if() like these

```
if(initiative == true && firstTimer > 0)
    {
        firstTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log ("First timer has finished!"); 
    }

    if(initiative == false && secondTimer > 0)
    {
        secondTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log ("Second timer has finished!"); 
    }
```

its not executing both if() blocks

this code

```
initiative = InitiativeOrder();
```

is being called every frame witch is im guessing 60 fps so for every frame per second it is executing that method and the chance however many times per second that it is true or false is why it seems that it is firing both if() blocks but really each frame that update fires its either true or false which is really fast

if you put that call in OnStart() it will only fire once like

```
void Start(){
 initiative = InitiativeOrder(); 
}
```

**EDIT YOUR CODE**

```
public float firstTimer = 2;
public float secondTimer = 10; 
public bool initiative; 
void Start(){
 initiative = InitiativeOrder();
}
void Update()
{



    if(initiative == true && firstTimer > 0)
    {
        firstTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log ("First timer has finished!"); 
    }

    if(initiative == false && secondTimer > 0)
    {
        secondTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log ("Second timer has finished!"); 
    }
}

public bool InitiativeOrder()
{
    float player =  Random.Range(1,10); 
    float enemy = Random.Range(1,10); 

    if(player > enemy)
    {
        return true; 
    }
    else if (player < enemy)
    {
        return false; 
    }
    else 
    {
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm still a little stuck though because even when I put the initialization in Start or OnStart it still does the rapid oscillation between true and false. Why would this be?

Comment: did you remove the ;'s from after your if()

Comment: did you get it how you want?

Comment: It's in start, the two > are gone, and it's still doing it. I must be missing something

Comment: try how i put in my EDIT YOUR CODE section

Comment: that's great. That works. The question is now how do I program it so the initiative variable can change after an if block has finished. If the first block is true and it counts down to zero, how can I recalculate initiative without making it oscillate like before?

Comment: put it back into Update() how you had it before, the semicolon after your if(); was messing everything up Update fires every frame

Comment: noooo! how could I make such a basic error! Thanks for not biting my head off :)